# When i tried to upload a folder to GITHUB it changed my local files to an older version

Tags: git, file, github

I tried to upload files to GITHUB , when I did this it changed all my local files to one with older version , which I previously had in the repository. The version I wanted to upload is no where to be found , not on GITHUB or locally. I suspect this could be because I may have ,merged master and main , I have no idea it was my first time wpusing GITHUB.  Please help I have a deadline for this.

I entered this first:
GitHub:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Add all my files"
git remote add origin https://github.com/yourusername/your-repo-name.git
git pull origin master
git push origin master
```

Then main and master had a conflict problem so I entered the following

```
git checkout main
git merge master
git push origin main
```

Sometimes it would say there's already an origin so I entered

```
git remote remove origin
```

Comment: Please, don't use unrelated tags like ci/cd, python, and github-actions. And please provide the commands that you've used. I'm pretty sure that `git push` can never change your local files.

Comment: Apologies I have changed my question with what I entered. I didn't change anything else.

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/

Comment: Do you actually know what the commands do, in particular, `git pull` and `git push`? To me it looks like you followed a tutorial blindly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your merge did as it was told, and updated the local working directory to reflect upstream changes. Unfortunately, while it did what it was told, what it was told doesn't match what you really wanted.

You should be able to see previous versions listed in `git log` or `git reflog`. To reset the repo to a particular version, use `git reset --hard $hash` (with the appropriate hash from `git log` or `git reflog`); note that a hard reset will overwrite anything that's changed since then.

You should only need to add the `origin` remote once; don't keep re-adding it, unless you've already removed it and want it back. You also don't need to `git init` a repo that already exists; use `git clone` instead.

Comment: thanks for your help this worked for me. just for future reference what do I do when I want to replace an older version of a remote file with a current local me? do I just do the same thing but start with git origin?

Comment: If you want to replace the remote version with an updated local version, run `git add $FILE` then `git commit` (add a descriptive commit message) and `git push origin $BRANCH_NAME`.